# "name 'log' is not defined" error django python

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the error "name 'log' is not defined". Below is my code, but I have almost the exact same code on a different file which works fine.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse
import json
from .models import *
import os, sys 

# Create your views here.
def count(request, start, step):
    try:
        stop = 100
        count_list = []
        while(start<stop):
            count_list.append(start)
            start = start + step
            return count_list
            return JsonResponse(count_list)
    except Exception as e:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        other = sys.exc_info()[0].__name__
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        errorType = str(exc_type)
        return JsonResponse({"isError": True, "error":str(e), "errorType":errorType, "function":fname, "line":exc_tb.tb_lineno, "log":log})
```

Comment: Why do you have two consecutive returns? An IDE should warn you about that. That `while` loop won't do anything either since you're returning unconditionally in it. And where do you define `log`? Are you missing an import?

Comment: I'm not really sure because I have the same imports in a different file but it still works.

Comment: Double check the other code that works, because this code as posted here will not work. If this exact code didn't give an error in a previous file, you must have never entered the `except` block with it. And note what I said about the `return`. `return JsonResponse(count_list)` will never be reached.

Comment: all good i fixed it up, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I've reformatted the last line of your function's return so I can point out the problem.

```py
return JsonResponse({
    "isError": True, 
    "error":str(e),
    "errorType":errorType,
    "function":fname,
    "line":exc_tb.tb_lineno,

    # this line below is the problem.
    "log":log 
})
```

Nowhere inside your `def count` function and nowhere in your imports at the top is the `log` name defined, this is why you are getting this error. Double-check your other script and see where you've defined that `log`.